# Bad models downloaded from Gazebo server

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using the DRC sim, and upon coloring a pointcloud (aggregated from the spinning laser) with the camera data, I noticed really weird issues on the table model that gets automatically downloaded into my .gazebo directory.  After hours of debugging, we realized that the model sdf file (both model.sdf and model-1.3.sdf for table) has a different collision geometry than visual geometry (like 10 cm difference in length and some small diff in height), which completely explains why I was seeing floor pixels on both sides of my table top in the colored clouds.

I would like to suggest/request that OSRF go through all models and make sure that visual and collision dimensions for DRC models and standard models downloaded from the Gazebo URI are consistent so that we don't have two different sensing modes seeing different things.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1038/bad-models-downloaded-from-gazebo-server/) by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See also [this related ticket on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/309/use-of-visual-model-instead-of-collision) on the use of visual vs. collision models for LIDAR sensors.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1